# If $G$ has a nontrivial centre, must every subgroup of index $3$ be normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

> If a group $G$ has a nontrivial centre, must every subgroup of index $3$ be normal?

$S_3$ yields an example of a group with a non-normal subgroup of index $3$, although it has a trivial centre. Moreover, for finite $G$, it's well-known that if $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, then any subgroup of index $p$ is normal. Hence the answer to this question is "yes" if $G$ is a finite group of odd order divisible by $3$.

I'm considering dihedral groups as possible counterexamples, but haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Can’t you fancy up your permutation example into a counterexample by direct products?

Comment: Randall's correct; you can just take $S_3 \times C_2$.

Comment: @Randall Thanks. Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 nah you go for it.  It’s good for you.

Comment: The statement is true however, for every non-trivial 3-group ...

Comment: But for 3-groups it's true even if they have trivial center.  (Yes, I do realize that only happens for infinite 3- groups.)

Comment: Also the trivial group is a finite 3-group with trivial center (and all its subgroups of index 3 are normal).